# Enable Shield in Org

Tags: shield

Looking at getting shield up and running.  To get the option to enable Shield, Field Audit Trail, and event monitoring, is that something I need to reach out to our success manager and have enabled for the org?  I am just trying to "Flip the switch".

Thanks!

Comment: Start reading from _Enable Shield Platform Encryption_ in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/spe_admins/spe_admins_get_started

Comment: Costs $$.  When we did it, there was a reduced bundle price to get all 3.  The field audit trail expansion of 20 to 60 was well worth it

Comment: @cropredy for the field audit expansion, mind if i ask why it was worth the $? I would have thought a home-grown trigger based solution would be a better value prop

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana the sheer convenience of being able to see field history on the objects with a bunch of fields that changed a lot was the draw.   Developers were busy building business function and we didn’t need them diverted for audit trail work.  I will say that we were primarily motivated to get encryption and the price for all 3 was ‘right’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your enviro. First you need to get a license.
Contact Salesforce for that. If it's a dev org you should have it.

Here is a trailhead on shield - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/spe_admins